# YUI3 + node.js = runInNewContext error

Tags: node.js, yui, yui3

I try to run this simple code in node.js:

```
var YUI = require("yui3");
YUI.use(function(Y) {
console.log('asdasd');
})
```

But I get the following error:

```
node.js:178
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'runInNewContext' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/yui3/0.5.34/package/lib/yui3-yui3.js:7:29)
        at Module._compile (module.js:404:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:410:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
    at require (module.js:348:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/yui3/0.5.34/package/lib/node-yui3.js:2:16
    at Object.use (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/yui3/0.5.34/package/lib/node-yui3.js:41:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/myDir/libs/nodejs-yui3/yui3_test.js:6:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:404:26)
```

How can I fix this?

[Edit]
I'm using: node v0.5.0-pre

Comment: did you expect YUI3 to support node.js ? I personally believe YUI3 only supports browsers.

Comment: @Raynos https://github.com/yui/nodejs-yui3

Comment: @BrandonTilley wow, that's neat :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce this. I followed these steps:

- Installed YUI3:

  ```
  [BinaryMuse ~/src]: npm install yui3
  [ lots of output ... ]
  npm info build Success: yui3@0.5.34
  npm info build Success: request@1.9.5
  npm info build Success: mime@1.2.1
  npm info build Success: express@2.2.2
  npm info build Success: connect@1.3.0
  npm info build Success: qs@0.1.0
  npm info build Success: htmlparser@1.7.3
  npm info build Success: yui3-core@3.3.0
  npm info build Success: jsdom@0.2.0
  npm ok
  ```
- Created the file `yui.js`:

  ```
  var YUI = require("yui3");

  YUI.use(function(Y) {
    console.log('asdasd');
  });
  ```
- Ran the program:

  ```
  [BinaryMuse ~/src]: node yui.js 
  asdasd
  ```

I know this doesn't really "answer" your question, but perhaps knowing that it works will point you in the right direction. Good luck!

[Update] I'm on Node v0.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

This error introduced in Node.js 0.5.0-pre, see discussion in [issue 203](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/203).
To fix this you can:

1. downgrade Node to 0.4.7
2. or remove two strings from yui3-yui3.js (don't know about yui3@0.5.34, but in yui3@0.6.0 variables are not used), see [this ticket](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/nodejs-yui3/ticket/8).